# Common project for all customers

Tags: php, project, webshop

I have developed a PHP webshop project which works independently for each customer. Meaning each customer installs own webshop source files, php.

I found out that this is a killer to maintain many websites so I decided to place the source files of the webshop in a common place in the server and create an alias on the apache server so all www customers have access to it.

Then each customer has own config file, log folder, template folder etc. in their own www folders.

I managed to do all of the stuff above. But my problem is the URL.

URLs will look as follows:
http://www.exampleshop.com/webshop/v1/index.php

I need to hide the webshop/v1 in the url so it looks as follows:
http://www.exampleshop.com/index.php

I played with url rewrite mod but it keeps telling that the index.php does not exist as it does look for the file in the root of exampleshop.com which is not correct, it is in /webshop/v1

Any ideas? alternatives.

Hope someone can help :-)

---

I managed to do the above with the followings :-)

```
RewriteEngine On
#for admin pages redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$/admin/index\.php$ /webshop/v1/admin/$1 [L]

#for webshop pages redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webshop/v1/$1 [L]
```

the aboves works, but the only problem is that it does not recognize the index file.
when I go to url without specifying a page it doesn't work as index file wont work. I have to type full url such as webshop.com/index.php to get it to work.

and is there a way to remove the extension too :-)

Solutions which works also without specifying index.php in url

```
#if no file specified, forward to index
RewriteRule ^$   webshop/v1/   [L]
#if no file specified, forward to index
RewriteRule ^admin/$   webshop/v1/admin/   [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webshop/v1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: So is each customer set up as a virtual host?

Comment: can you edit in .htaccess you've been trying to get to work?

Comment: yes I can edit .htaccess but it doesnt work :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd route the requests a application-level based on the host.

Say you have the files installed on your server, and various domains pointing at this server, i.e. customer1.com, customer2.com, customer3.com etc. Then, in your `index.php` file, just detect which domain the files are being accessed from and switch configuration settings as required.

You could have a database table that maps settings to domains, so you can do a database query and fetch settings if you didn't want to use file-based configuration.

**UPDATE**

Well, in that case, you want a .htaccess rule. Please this in your root **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$   webshop/v1/   [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webshop/v1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this in your **/webshop/v1/** directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # for admin pages redirection
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /webshop/v1/admin/$1 [L]

    # for webshop pages redirection
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webshop/v1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thats what I am doing. In my index.php i find the user path (domain) and load its local configuration which loads database variables etc..

but that will not help to remove the subfolders in the url

Comment: thanks martin

I managed to do the above with the followings :-)


RewriteEngine On
#for admin pages redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$/admin/index\.php$ /webshop/v1/admin/$1 [L]


#for webshop pages redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webshop/v1/$1 [L]


the aboves works, but the only problem is that it does not recognize the index file.


when I go to http://www.webshop.com it doesn't work. I have to type http://www.webshop.com/index.php to get it to work.

Comment: alternativly look at my edited question for better formatting :-)

Comment: You're including `index.php` in the pattern. Remove it (and the ending delimiter) and anything after `/admin` will get passed as desired. You also had your matching pattern in the wrong place. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: the first rewrite works actually without having the other rewrite rules in  /webshop/v1/ directory:? So what does the rules for webshop/v1 root do if it does work without it?

Comment: or maybe not :-) need to test it a bit more :-)

Comment: Martin it doesnt work with your solution. I can get it to work when I place the second code on the user root and not webshop root

Comment: But still having the problem with index file. If nothing is typed then it does not show the default index.php file.

Comment: The part that does not work is css and images, they are placed on the client root and not webshop, so these should be retrieved from client root?

Comment: @JosephMerdas I've set up a VirtualHost on my local development environment, copied your directory structure, and my `.htaccess` and works fine for me. The only thing I can suggest is to check your Apache error log.

Comment: I got it working also without index.php. I only needed to include the code one place, in user root folder and not app root. But you helped, thanks.

Look at my post to see what I came up with. Thi works too, so what is the different?

Comment: I said it before. The reason yours does not work is because you're checking if `index.php` is present in the URL, and only rewriting if it _is_. Compare yours to mine: I don't have `index.php` in the first segment (the pattern to match) which is why mine works.

Answer (score 0):

`VirtualHost` or `Alias` directives  should fix it.

Comment: virtualhost, can you tell more how to achieve that :-)